# Python import cannot find module

Tags: python

Brand new to python and can't manage to get my import resolved when I debug my test within vscode.

Project structure:

```
a/b/c/d/service/functions/s3_proxy.py
a/b/c/d/service/functions/__init__.py

a/b/c/d/service/tests/test_s3_proxy.py
a/b/c/d/service/tests/__init__.py
```

**test_s3_proxy.py**

```
from functions import s3_proxy
```

I get an error that funcitons module isn't found.

**I tried these things:**

- I tried putting an `__init__.py` in service
- I tried `from ..functions import s3_proxy`

Comment: Is `test_s3_proxy.py` a standalone program?  If so, then you need to add `../functions` to the Python path in `sys.path`.  You can get that from `os.abspath(os.dirname(__file__)+'/..')`.

Comment: Did you try `from ..functions import s3_proxy` ?
Also, I sometimes use this:
```import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from functions import s3_proxy```

Comment: It's meant to house the unit tests for s3_proxy. What makes it a stand alone program? Forgive my python ignorance.

Comment: @KarolŻak yes I did (had a typo in my question, but tried that)

Comment: `import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from functions import s3_proxy`

Comment: @KarolŻak just tried your sys.path.append solution and same result "No module named functions"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Have you tried `from .functions import s3_proxy`?

Comment: I added additional context that the exception occurs when I debug my test within VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports doesn't work. You need to add the path `a/b/c/d/service/functions` to your python system path

```
import os
import sys
path_to_functions = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'functions')
sys.path.append(path_to_functions)
import s3_proxy
```

or replace `path_to_functions` with full literal path to the folder `functions`

```
path_to_functions = os.path.join('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'service', 'functions')
```

or (to get the `from functions import`)

```
path_to_functions = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)
sys.path.append(path_to_functions)
from functions import s3_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add s3_proxy.py to your modules.

Here is an example snippet.

```
from functions import s3_proxy
from sys import modules
modules['s3_proxy'] = s3_proxy
```

From there you can use the s3_proxy module as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use an absolute path, like this

> from [drive letter]:/[example folder]/ functions import s3_proxy

Comment: That won't work to well when it's deployed outside my machine. Absolute paths are generally evil.